# NetBeans - how to restore JSTL 1.1 lib jars

Tags: java, libraries, netbeans6.5

For some reason my lib as JSTL 1.1 in the libraries list is empty... The jars paths were removed from the classpath with **Tools -> Libraries** dialog... 
How can I restore the JSTL jars back for NetBeans6.5.1 ?

So my question is what jars JSTL 1.1 lib should contain and where to look them for in NetBeans installed folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my system, JSTL 1.1 library contains the jars:

```
jstl.jar
standard.jar
```

As to where they are located, they're buried in Netbeans.

Specifically, (on my machine, a Mac) there is a .netbeans folder in my home folder.

Pretty sure this exists on Windows as well.

Within .netbeans, there's a folder for your specific version (6.5 in this case).

Within that, is a modules directory.

The jars are located at:

```
.netbeans/6.5/modules/ext/jstl.jar
.netbeans/6.5/modules/ext/standard.jar
```

The association of the jars to the library are made in a file:

```
.netbeans/6.5/modules/org-netbeans-modules-web-jstl11.jar
```

If these files are all intact, you might want to try and remove the folder:

```
.netbeans/6.5/var/cache
```

Netbeans creates this, and if Netbeans start going stupid on you, erasing it and letting it rebuild it may clean things up for you.

Comment: I have found this jar as "org-netbeans-modules-web-jstl11.jar" in "C: \... NetBeans 6.5.1\enterprise5\modules" folder. Should I add this jar to lib classpath or I should add, as you say, those two ".netbeans/6.5/modules/ext/jstl.jar
.netbeans/6.5/modules/ext/standard.jar"?

Comment: You're probably best off simply creating a new library for your project, then add those two jars, and make sure you click the option to copy the jars to your local library directory. Then they'll always be with the project.

Comment: The thing is I have library JSTL 1.1 in the NB6.5.1 "Class Libraries" libraries list but it is empty. All jars by mark JSTL 1.1 were removed that's why I just want to re-add the jars paths as it used to be before their paths were removed. but I am not sure should I add the "org-netbeans-modules-web-jstl11.jar" or the two you mentioned as ".netbeans/6.5/modules/ext/jstl.jar .netbeans/6.5/modules/ext/standard.jar"? Please give me a little more details at the point.

Comment: I'm saying "fixing" this is not something I think you can do easily, save for re-installing Netbeans. Instead, since you have the jars on your system, create a NEW library for your project, add those two jars to it (and make sure you copy the jars in to your project), and then simply remove the Netbeans JSTL 1.1 lib from your project. You simply replace the broken library with a local working one.

Comment: I don't have JSTL 1.1 lib in my current projects but in the IDE "Class Libraries" list only so I don't need use it as an external one. Is it right if I add to JSTL 1.1 lib the path for org-netbeans-modules-web-jstl11.jar or I should add the two jars paths as ".netbeans/6.5/modules/ext/jstl.jar .netbeans/6.5/modules/ext/standard.jar" instead?

Comment: You shouldn't touch the JSTL 1.1 lib at all -- it's managed by one of Netbeans plugins. So, it's effectively hands off for you. Somehow it's been corrupted. If you want, you can try and uninstall the "Java Web Applications" plugin, and see if re-installing it will recover and fix the library for you. Otherwise, create a new, from scratch,library specific for you project by importing and copying the jstl.jar and standard.jar.

Comment: So I am saying. Is it possible to restore it with no IDE reinstalling or something? Just manually add the lost paths and that's all? And, by the way, I didn't find the jars in my sys by the paths as ".netbeans\6.5\" there is no "\modules" folder :S